# Setup an app to use single Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate for Development and Production

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Recently Apple introduced a new type of APNS certificates - **Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate**.

It seemed for me that it should allow to have one certificate to use on both Development and Production (Sandbox and Production). This was really wanted feature because my backend uses the Azure Notification Hub to send pushes and contains only one available space for a certificate (Sandbox or Production).

I tried to follow official [docs provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)  (Creating a Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate) but with no luck - the new certificate applies only for Distribution . And even on theirs screenshots I see that this certificate applies only for Distribution mode and not for the Development and this is what confuses me 
- [Creating a Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9TeB.jpg)

This is why I will appreciate any guidance or advice which will explain how it should work, and did I understand the purpose of those certificates properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should appear - "Configurable" for development and "Enabled" for distribution. But it'll work for development as well.

Comment: Thank you, I've verified this and this seems to be true. The reason why I was not able to see the push on a device was... Azure Hub and that is you should select the mode for the certificate manually (Sandbox or Production). Unfortunately for now it is not possible to just upload the certificate once and use it for both development and production with Azure Hubs, it anyway requires you to define the target in Azure Admin Panel. But according to the original question - Universal Certificate works as it is sound, but for me it is strange how it is displayed in Member Center anyway.

Comment: It is possible to create APNS for message and VOIP into a single certificate.

Comment: How do I create universal certificate ? I couldn't find any options in developer portel.

Comment: @VineeshTP have found a way to create universal certificate for both APNs and VOIP?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem looking for how to "Generate a universal APNs client SSL certificate". After a while, I managed to make it work. In the Apple developer console:

1. create a **Key** (not a certificate)
2. write the name of your key a select "APNs" service.
3. Download your .p8 key.

Then you have to use this .p8 file in your call.